# Hadoop command not found in terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop in ubuntu
after setting these lines in the .bashrc of Hadoop installation

```
export HADOOP_HOME="/Desktop/hadoop-1.2.1"
set PATH ="$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin"
export PATH
```

I wrote in the terminal

```
hadoop version
```

I got:

```
hadoop: command not found
```

Comment: Try `hadoop --version`? to see where is installed do `which hadoop`?

Comment: I did
and it show it to the same message 
hadoop: command not found

Comment: have you enable your settings by relogin or enable it manually with `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I did
but the same show to me
hadoop:command not found

Comment: The answer posted by cdarke is correct. Please search next time. You can find the answer in every hadoop installation guide.

Comment: thank you
but I found another way and I solve it :)

Comment: @dalyaraad how did you solve it?

Comment: @saadi simply go to the directory of Hadoop. I mean where the Hadoop is saved, then use the same command, and this command didn't work just used instead of it hdfs.
Hope to you all the best

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
set PATH ="$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin"
```

is not what you think it means in `bash`.  In Bash `set` is used for many things, but not for assigning variables.  That line actually sets the command-line arguments (*unnamed parameters*) accessed as `$1` and `$2`.

You probably mean:

```
export HADOOP_HOME="/Desktop/hadoop-1.2.1"
export PATH="$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin"
```

Note that spaces are not allowed around the `=`.

Make sure you then "source" the `.bashrc` file before testing.